# Excel VBA: Need advice on code architecture: Data looping and data extraction

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, architecture

The task is quite simple but I can't get all my parts together.

First, some minor data manipulation. I have a master table with data, where als rows with the same date have to be combined and extracted onto another sheet. Then again some minor data manipulation happens.

```
'         ReplaceValue = Replace(ReplaceValue, i, "") 'Replace(expression, find, replace, [ start, [ count, [ compare ]]])
'    Next i

Columns("G").replace What:="[0%]", _
                            Replacement:="", _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            MatchCase:=False, _
                            SearchFormat:=False, _
                            ReplaceFormat:=False

Columns("G").replace What:="[10%]", _
                            Replacement:="", _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            MatchCase:=False, _
                            SearchFormat:=False, _
                            ReplaceFormat:=False
Columns("G").replace What:="[50%]", _
                            Replacement:="", _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            MatchCase:=False, _
                            SearchFormat:=False, _
                            ReplaceFormat:=False
Columns("G").replace What:="[200%]", _
                            Replacement:="", _
                            LookAt:=xlPart, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            MatchCase:=False, _
                            SearchFormat:=False, _
                            ReplaceFormat:=False

Error2:
End Sub
```

This is obviosuly copied from somewhere. My thoughts: I need something to loop through rows and columns. the columns are usually fixed at column 11. The bottom end is marked by many, many placeholder rows containing only "#N/A" (don't ask why).

```
Sub 2 ()
Dim arr As Variant Dim i As Long, j As Long Dim EndRow as Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Do I need that?

With Sheets("Mastertable") EndRow = .Range("A:A").Find(what:="#N/A",after:=.Range("A1"), searchdirection:=xlNext).Row End With

'then save the value of EndRow and use it for the next procedure (or function?)

arr = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Mastertable").Range(A1:K-EndRow) 'how to enter this correctly? 'K := 11th column, EndRow := last row just found

For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1) For j = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)

'Here stuff has to happen

Next j

Next i

'Extraction of data 

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Mastertable").Range("Mastertable").Value = arr

End Sub
```

How can you say "group my stuff from my array depending on the date", export similar dates to new sheets that are placed next to other new sheets in chronological order, name them with the respective date. I don't know how to tackle this  task, maybe you can guide me here

There's a column filled with names of companies. The generated sheets per date only contain one company at a time (no similar dates with different companies). So the column has to be checked, if there's a value, and then the whole column shall be filled with that text.

```
Sub 3 ()

'no idea
```

It seems to me this step should be integrated into the part with the array, otherwise I have to loop through all new worksheets and then loop within the sheets again... again guidance is needed

Comment: Why does the *the whole column shall be filled with that text.* if *There's a column filled with names of companies* ? Which columns are Date and Company ?

Comment: The first code snippet can be replaced with `Columns("G").Replace What:="[*%]", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart` if you don't have other percentages that fit the pattern and you want to keep them. For the rest, there is not nearly enough information. Try harder. You need to accurately explain what needs to be copied and where. Adding a screenshot of your source sheet and one of your destination sheets would clarify quite a lot.

Comment: Please share data layout and sample data in OP.

Comment: I am not able to anonymize the data, it would be too clear, what I'm doing and where I'm working. Maybe I'm not capable enough, too, bear with me.

I have a mastertable that works as database. One row in the database is called a task and has everything in it, notes, names etc. to complete this special task (construction, project mgmt.). Basically I sort all this stuff per date. Every date consists of several task rows a certain company has to do. The challenge for me is to generate worksheets with the date as name. Every task assigned to this day is done by only one company.

Comment: The database is incomplete, that's why after copying the tasks sorted by date into a single worksheet, I want to simply copy the company name of one task to every other, since one day only has one company name! That's a way to "complete" the database; please do not ask for any other procedures, I am instructed to do it exactly this way and can not change the logic of the process

Comment: The main focus is Sub 2, here I want the splitting of the mastertable to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Add Worksheets Corresponding to Column Values (Dates)

[image]

```vb
Sub ExtractCompanyData()
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const SRC_SHEET_NAME As String = "MasterTable"
    Const DATA_COLUMNS As String = "A:K"
    Const DATE_COLUMN As Long = 2
    Const COMPANY_COLUMN As Long = 3
    Const DST_FIRST_CELL As String = "A1"
    Const DST_DATE_FORMAT As String = "mm\/dd\/yyyy"
    Const DST_SHEET_NAME_DATE_FORMAT As String = "mm-dd-yyyy"
    Const COPY_HEADERS As Boolean = True
 
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Return the source data in an array ('sData').
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET_NAME)
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.UsedRange.Columns(DATA_COLUMNS)
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.Rows.Count
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = srg.Columns.Count
    Dim sData() As Variant: sData = srg.Value
    
    ' An Incomplete Description of the Dictionary and the Collection
    ' A dictionary consists of two arrays: one is called 'Keys' and the other
    ' is called 'Items' ('Values'). Each key has an associated item
    ' and they form a so-called 'key-value pair'.
    ' Each key needs to be unique while its item can hold various data types,
    ' in this case, a collection ('object').
    ' A collection is similar but simpler.
    ' Each of a collection's 'item' needs to be unique.
    ' The collection is used because it is more efficient and you can simply
    ' add just an item to it while you need to add a value pair to a dictionary.
    
    ' Return the unique dates ('sDate') from the source array ('sData')
    ' in the 'keys' of a dictionary.
    ' Each key's corresponding 'item' will hold a collection whose 'items'
    ' will hold the rows ('sr') where each date ('sDate', key) was found.
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim sDate As Variant, sr As Long
    
    For sr = 2 To srCount ' skip headers
        sDate = sData(sr, DATE_COLUMN)
        If IsDate(sDate) Then
            If Not dict.Exists(sDate) Then
                ' Create the 'sDate' key in the dictionary
                ' and add a new collection to the key's associated item.
                dict.Add sDate, New Collection
                ' or:
                'Set dict(sDate) = New Collection
            End If
            dict(sDate).Add sr ' add the row to the items of the collection
        End If
    Next sr

    ' Loop through the keys (dates) of the dictionary, and by applying
    ' the required logic, copy the data to the destination worksheet.

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim dws As Worksheet, drg As Range, ddrg As Range
    Dim dData() As Variant, sRow As Variant
    Dim dr As Long, idr As Long, drCount As Long, c As Long
    Dim dwsName As String, Company As String, IsCompanyFound As Boolean
    
    ' Loop through the keys (dates) of the dictionary.
    For Each sDate In dict.Keys
        
        ' Define the destination array.
        drCount = dict(sDate).Count - COPY_HEADERS
        ReDim dData(1 To drCount, 1 To cCount)
        
        ' Write the headers to the destination array.
        ' Also, determine the used destination array rows ('idr', 'dr')
        ' i.e. the inital row, the first row to be written to minus one.
        If COPY_HEADERS Then
            For c = 1 To cCount
                dData(1, c) = sData(1, c)
            Next c
            idr = 1
        Else
            idr = 0
        End If
        dr = idr
        
        ' Loop through the items ('sRow') of the collection ('dict(sDate)'),
        ' held by the current key's ('dDate') corresponding item ('dict(sDate)'),
        ' and write the values from each corresponding row ('sRow')
        ' of the source array ('sData') to the next row ('dr')
        ' of destination array ('dData') skipping the company column.
        ' Also, attempt to determine the company name.
        For Each sRow In dict(sDate)
            dr = dr + 1
            For c = 1 To cCount
                If c <> COMPANY_COLUMN Then
                    dData(dr, c) = sData(sRow, c)
                End If
            Next c
            If Not IsCompanyFound Then
                Company = CStr(sData(sRow, COMPANY_COLUMN))
                If Len(Company) > 0 Then IsCompanyFound = True
            End If
        Next sRow
        
        ' Loop through the rows ('dr') of the destination array ('dData')
        ' and write the company name ('Company') to the company column.
        If IsCompanyFound Then
            For dr = idr + 1 To drCount
                dData(dr, COMPANY_COLUMN) = Company
            Next dr
            IsCompanyFound = False ' reset for the next iteration
        End If
        
        ' Determine the destination worksheet name ('dwsName').
        dwsName = Format(sDate, DST_SHEET_NAME_DATE_FORMAT)
        
        ' Delete an existing same named sheet.
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            On Error Resume Next
                wb.Sheets(dwsName).Delete
            On Error GoTo 0
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        
        ' Add a new worksheet ('dws') and rename it accordingly.
        Set dws = wb.Sheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
        dws.Name = dwsName
        
        ' Copy the values from the destination array ('dData')
        ' to the destination range ('drg').
        Set drg = dws.Range(DST_FIRST_CELL).Resize(drCount, cCount)
        drg.Value = dData
        
        ' Apply formatting to the destination (range, worksheet).
        With drg
            ' Format headers and reference the destination data range ('ddrg').
            If COPY_HEADERS Then
                With .Rows(1)
                    .Font.Bold = True
                End With
                Set ddrg = drg.Resize(drCount - 1).Offset(1)
            Else
                Set ddrg = drg
            End If
            ' Format the destination data range ('ddrg').
            With ddrg
                ' Format the destination date column.
                With ddrg.Columns(DATE_COLUMN)
                    .NumberFormat = DST_DATE_FORMAT
                End With
            End With
            ' Format the entire destination columns.
            .EntireColumn.AutoFit
        End With
        
    Next sDate
    
    ' Additional Ideas
    
    'sws.Activate
    'wb.Save

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Company data extracted.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

**A Visual Presentation of the Populated Dictionary**

[image]

Comment: It works! But I learned almost nothing. Any possibility I can contact you, so we can go through the code? I have a lot of questions

Comment: I corrected and extended a few comments. Feel free to ask a few questions in this comment section. If you have many, there is an email address on my profile page. Send an email, and if it's not too demanding, I'll answer it. This site is usually used to ask one question (by far less demanding than yours) with a closely related follow-up or two.

Comment: What is happening here: "dData(dr, c)" ? dData is the object, dr and c are arguments for...?

What do I need to leave out, if I don't wan't the company name to be searched after?

Comment: `For Each sRow In dict(sDate)`
 `dr = dr + 1 For c = 1 To cCount`
 `dData(dr, c) = sData(sRow, c)`
`Next c`
`Next sRow`


Should be only this piece, right?

Comment: Exactly. You've been busy. And you should remove the entire block `If IsCompanyFound... End If`. I guess.

Comment: Alright one last question: If I want to copy conditional formatting from the mastertable to the sheets, can I use this 
 `rngDst.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllMergingConditionalFormats` 
after
 `.EntireColumn.AutoFit` ?

Comment: I don't think so but I've never used this option anyway so I can't help you there. Sorry.